# How to use Direct3D11CaptureFramePool in NET 5 / 6

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime, directx-11

**Alternative title:** *WinRT support for IDirect3DDevice*

I've an application that uses the "[Direct3D11CaptureFramePool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool?view=winrt-22000)" class to capture the content of an application window as shown here ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture/CaptureSampleCore/BasicCapture.cs))

I would like to port this example to NET 6.0

How to port WinRT code is described here [link](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/docs/interop.md)
This worked as expected. But it was not possible for the `IDirect3DDevice` required by the [CreateFreeThreaded method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool.createfreethreaded?view=winrt-22000)

**How can i port this code to NET 6.0**

```
    uint hr = CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(dxgiDevice.NativePointer, out IntPtr pUnknown);
    if (hr == 0)
    {
        device = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pUnknown) as IDirect3DDevice;
        Marshal.Release(pUnknown);
    }
```

There is no FromAbi method for IDrect3DDEvice as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/docs/interop.md#ref-counting)

**Edit:**

I have the Interface Type, I have a pointer to a IUnknown object, but i cannot get an instance because the Code to get an object for a IUnknown pointer has changed. There is no  `Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.IDirect3DDevice.FromAbi(pUnknown)`

**Edit 2:**

I've created a sample repo to reproduce the problem:
https://github.com/Amberg/GraphicsCaptureItemNet6Problem

This code works with NET 4.8 but not with NET 6. I belive because the
call `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pUnknown)` should be replaced with
`IDirect3DDevice.FromAbi(pUnknown)` but there is no such method

```
internal class Program
{

[DllImport(
        "d3d11.dll",
        EntryPoint = "CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
        )]
static extern UInt32 CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(IntPtr dxgiDevice, out IntPtr graphicsDevice);

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using var sharpDxDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);
    IDirect3DDevice direct3dDevice = CreateDirect3DDeviceFromSharpDXDevice(sharpDxDevice);

    // this will throw internal cast exception 
    using var framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.CreateFreeThreaded(
                        direct3dDevice,
                        DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
                        2,
                        new SizeInt32(64, 64));

}

private static IDirect3DDevice CreateDirect3DDeviceFromSharpDXDevice(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device sharpDxDevice)
{
    IDirect3DDevice device = null;
    using (var dxgiDevice = sharpDxDevice.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device3>())
    {
        uint hr = CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(dxgiDevice.NativePointer, out IntPtr pUnknown);
        if (hr == 0)
        {
            // with NET 6 there should be something like 
            // IDirect3DDevice.FromAbi(pUnknown)
            // see here https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/docs/interop.md#create-rcw
            device = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pUnknown) as IDirect3DDevice;
            Marshal.Release(pUnknown);
        }
    }
    return device;
}
}
```

Comment: Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.IDirect3DDevice is available directly in .NET/C# if you make sure your .NET 6 project has a TargetFramework that includes "windows", like `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` see C#/WinRT common issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/

Comment: Yes - I did that.
I have the Interface as Type available, I Have a pointer to a IUnknown object, but i cannot get a valid instance

Comment: Note sure what your problem is. Can you provide a full reproducing sample?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thx - I've created a repo to show the problem https://github.com/Amberg/GraphicsCaptureItemNet6Problem

Comment: I am also currently struggling to get to capture windows in Windows 11 that are in the background / without focus. For Windows 10 BitBlt was working that is broken now on W11 for some reason. Is there a way to get WindowsRuntimeMarshal in NET 6.0? Seems it's the only that I am missing and isn't available to create the GraphicsCaptureItem from my hWnd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .NET 6 and CsWinRT, you can write your `CreateDirect3DDeviceFromSharpDXDevice` function like this:

```
private static IDirect3DDevice CreateDirect3DDeviceFromSharpDXDevice(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device sharpDxDevice)
{
    if (CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(sharpDxDevice.NativePointer, out var punk) != 0)
        return null;

    return WinRT.MarshalInterface<IDirect3DDevice>.FromAbi(punk);
}
```

Comment: Thank you  a lot!! [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] was the key..
You saved my day

Comment: @ManuelAmstutz - in fact, it's more simple :-) I've updated my answer